# Calculation of possible combinations if the number of possible properties and their possible states is unknown

Tags: math

I have an unknown number of properties, and each property has an unknown number of possible states. How can I calculate the number of possible combinations?

It's hard enough for me to formulate it mathematically. That's why I can't get it into my code.

If all properties could have the same number of states, the number of possible combinations would be simply `number_of_possible_combinations = number_possible_states^number_possible_properties`.

However, that is not the case.

A coded example would be helpful, or a mathematical formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply all the possible number of states; for example

- 3 states
- 2 states
- 11 states

gives a total of `2 * 3 * 11 = 66` possible combinations

The case where the number of states is fixed is just a special case of this formula.

In mathematical terms is the product of the cardinality of the sets of states:

[image]

Comment: @maxischl: this IS a formula :-) ... the mathematical symbol for it is Π (uppercase π), like a sum, but using product instead.